# TypeError: _store_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__.default.subscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a main App component and subscribe normally to the store:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(store.getState());
      this.setState(store.getState());
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div id="App">
          <MainNavbar />
          <ContentHandler />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

On `store.js` everything works fine if I create the store only with the root reducer:

```
const store = createStore(reduceAppState);
```

Nevertheless, if I create it passing saga as a middleware:

```
    import { createStore } from 'redux'
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools';
    import reduceAppState from './reducers'

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()
    const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({trace: true, traceLimit: 25})

    const store = createStore(reduceAppState, undefined, composeEnhancers(
    sagaMiddleware
));

    export default store;
```

I get this error:

[image]

Which pretty much sounds like a bug. Couldn't find anything on google. Do you know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: I had to `applyMiddleware` on sagaMiddleware:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools';
import reduceAppState from './reducers'

const sagaMiddleware = typeof createSagaMiddleware === 'function' ? createSagaMiddleware() : createSagaMiddleware.default()
const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({trace: true, traceLimit: 25})

const store = createStore(reduceAppState, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
));

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the rid of problem. You can add the redux chrome extension and this line of code need to add in your redux store :

```
**conststore=createStore(rootReducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());**
```

your overall code of redux store gonna be :

`import { createStore } from "redux"; import rootReducers from "./reducers"; const store=createStore(rootReducers,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()); export default store;`